# Style are not applied in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-theme, android-styles

I have created a button style defines in the `themes.xml` as below:

```
    <style name="MyAppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.06</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/brand04</item>
    </style>
```

I apply it as followed:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable name="text"  type="String"/>
    </data>

    <Button
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme.Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:letterSpacing="0.5"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:text="@{text}"/>
</layout>
```

I am using `include` to include the button into different layout.

The style is never applied

any idea why ?

Comment: use `style="@style/MyAppTheme.Button"` instead of `android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme.Button"`

Comment: @Kartik it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your root theme parent not the `Button` parent

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge">
</?
```

[image: Theme.xml]

[image: include_button_xml]

Answer (score 0):

you need to use AppCompatbutton.
You can then apply style.